# Compressing files with python

Tags: python, string, compression

I finally figured out a way to compress any string(it can be number, binary or hex in the string format). Now I want that when I give a path for any file then the program will read bytes of the file and then compress it as a string. and then store the compressed string in a file. How can I achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you googled for : how to read bytes from file ? and How to write to a file ?

Comment: @azro Yes I did and able to read and get the binary data of a file but the problem is that when I compressed the binary data and store it in a text file the data, data gets bigger. I want a solution to store the compressed string to a file

Comment: Plese shareyour code, by [edit]int your post ;)